# Fundamental group of $\mathbb G_m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I had a look at de Jong's notes (http://math.columbia.edu/~phlee/CourseNotes/EtaleFundamental.pdf) and I encountered example 7.2.

It says that for $\mathbb G_m=\mathbb A^1-0$ over $k$ with characteristic 0, Riemann-Hurwitz implies that the maps $x\mapsto x^n$ are cofinal (i.e. initial?) and this gives the fundamental group as $ \hat {\mathbb Z}$ with some twist.

I know the Riemann-Hurwitz formula but I don't see the rest of the implications. Any enlightenment? I'm mainly wondering about the covers, but if anyone could explain or reference an explanation for the twist part I would be grateful as well.

Comment: There's an argument in [these notes; at the beginning of page 7](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/etale-cohomology.pdf). It's outlined for $\mathbb{C}$ but the Riemann-Hurwitz formula is more general; [see here for instance](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C1B). The last part is the literal definition of the twist: $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1):=\varprojlim_n \mu_n(\overline{k})$.

Comment: @Eoin Thanks. I had to stare at it for a while but I think it's starting to make sense to me somewhat.